# "target is undefined" error when running dbt

Tags: dbt

I have a `dbt_project.yml` like:

```
name: rdb
profile: rdb
source-paths: ['models']
version: "0.1"

models:
  rdb:
    schema: cin
    materialized: table
    post-hook: 'grant select on {{ this }} to rer'
    on-run-end: 
        # TODO: fix
        - 'grant usage on schema "{{ target.schema }}" to rer'
```

DBT has worked really well. But with the `on-run-end` entry, it fails with `Compilation Error  'target' is undefined`. With that line commented out, it works fine.

Am I making a basic mistake? Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your post-hook should actually look like this:

```yaml
on-run-end:
 - "{% for schema in schemas %}grant usage on schema {{ schema }} to rer;{% endfor %}"
```

The dbt docs for the [on-run-end context](https://docs.getdbt.com/reference/dbt-jinja-functions/on-run-end-context) explain this in detail, but long story short: because a dbt run may touch tables in different schemas on the target database, there is no single `target.schema` value to which you can apply the grant statement. Instead, the context provides you with a list of schema names called `schemas` that you need to loop through. That list has one or more elements.

The `target` in dbt is the configuration data for the adapter, like account, user, port, or schema. `this` is about the database object that is being written, and also includes a field `schema`. Finally, the `on-run-end` context provides the list of schemas, so that you are not forced to make redundant grant statements for each table or view, but can make just a single grant for each schema.

Answer (score 2):

My hunch is you do not need to quote the jinja template. Try:

```
on-run-end:
    - 'grant usage on schema {{ target.schema }} to rer'
```

See [this](https://discourse.getdbt.com/t/the-exact-grant-statements-we-use-in-a-dbt-project/430) for reference.

Comment: This would be my guess as well, with the quotes in place it probably renders the SQL as `... on schema "target.schema" to rer` or something like that. You want a literal substitution here so leave the quotes out.